# Part and section in fancyhdr header of (article documentclass)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using the fancyhdr package in an `article` with the following code

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
```

At the moment `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` give the section and subsection titles. My subsections are pretty short and on a two-page spread there's a big chance the subsection title is actually on the page, so I don't need it in the header to refer to it. But I do have several `part*`s to my document.

I would like to use the part name (on the even pages) and the section name (on the odd pages) like so:

```
|  15       Third part* title      |      §2 2nd section title    16  |
|                                  |                                  |
|  Content of the 15th page,       |      Content of the 16th page,   |
|  continuing to the next          |      continuing to the next      |
|  line.                           |      line.                       |
|                                  |                                  |
|                                  |                                  |
|                                  |                                  |
|                                  |                                  |
|                                  |                                  |
|                                  |                                  |
|                                  |                                  |
```

I'm pasting a MWE for testing purposes

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}

\begin{document}

\part*{First part title}

\section{First section title}

Abc

\newpage

\subsection{First subsection title}

Def

\newpage

\subsection{Second subsection title}

Ghi

\newpage

\part*{Second part title}

\section{Second section title}

Jkl

\newpage

Mno

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, starred sectioning commands do not automatically set the headers in any case. From your MWE, however, I assume that you would like them to. This code uses `etoolbox` to patch both the unstarred and starred commands to mark the headers. The section and subsectioning commands are redefined using modified code from `fancyhdr`'s documentation.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand\subsectionmark[1]{\relax}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\markboth{}{}}{\markboth{#1}{}}{\typeout{done patching part!}}{\typeout{oh dear! could not patch part command...}}
\patchcmd{\@spart}{\nobreak}{\nobreak\markboth{#1}{}}{\typeout{done patching starred part!}}{\typeout{oh dear! could not patch starred part command...}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

  \part*{First part title}

  \section{First section title}

  Abc

  \newpage

  \subsection{First subsection title}

  Def

  \newpage

  \subsection{Second subsection title}

  Ghi

  \newpage

  \part*{Second part title}

  \section{Second section title}

  Jkl

  \newpage

  Mno

\end{document}
```

[image: modified headers]

Comment: I'm using `\pagestyle{empty}` for the title and contents pages (like `\pagestyle{empty} \maketitle \newpage \tableofcontents \clearpage \pagestyle{fancy}`). In combination with your code, I'm getting "oh dear! could not patch [starred] part command..." and the corresponding header remains empty. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I added that code to my example, added a title etc. in the preamble, and it recompiled fine with the title and contents pages. Can you update your question with an MWE I can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The problem was with using the hyperref package, which should be loaded after your code to work properly. Thank you!

Comment: @Earthliŋ Ah, yes. That makes sense. Since `hyperref` will be changing those commands, too. (And `hyperref` likes being loaded late, in most cases.) Glad you figured it out!